# Does this function maps bounded sequences to bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying assignment questions of real analysis of my institute and could not approach this particular question.

> Let $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f'(x)| < \infty$. Then does f maps bounded sequences to bounded sequences.

I tried with counterexamples like 1/x and x and some others related but couldn't contradict it. Neither I have any idea on how to prove it.

So, its my request too you to guide me!

Comment: Have you learned about Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: I think the mean value theorem could be helpful here.

Comment: @Zim No wasn't covered in the course

Comment: In the spirit of @Clayton 's comment, if $(a_n) $ is a bounded sequence, what can you say about $\frac{ |f(0)- f(a_k)| }{|0-a_k|}$? Using that answer, find an upper bound of $|f(0)- f(a_k)|$ in terms of $|a_k|$. Finally, If  $|f(0)- f(a_k)|$ is bounded in terms of $k$ show that so is $|f(a_k)|$.